# Solving gradient of an especial heat equation

Tags: graph-theory, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, laplacian, heat-equation

In my research I came up with a gradient of heat equation on a edge-weighted graph as:

\begin{equation*}
  \nabla_w T_t(t,w) + T(t,w) . \nabla_w L_w + L_w . \nabla_w T(t,w) = 0
\end{equation*}
where  $L_w$ is weighted Laplacian of the defined graph.
Is there any idea how to solve this pde for a given initial condition $T_0=0$ and boundary conditions $T(0,w)=u_0$?

**Update:**

There is an idea that to separate to:

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{lcl}
      S & = &\nabla_w T, \\
      S_t & = & \nabla_w T_t + T . \nabla_w L_w + L_w . S, \\
      S_0 & = & 0 .
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

I would be pleased to get some hints!!

Comment: Solve in which sense? Give a closed form solution for given boundary conditions (of some kind)? Show that solutions exist uniquely?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I meant a closed form solution for given initial and boundary conditions.